# Scikit classification comparison

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, evaluation, precision-recall

i compared results of testset of 6 classifications and got Random forest with highest accuracy and NB as the lowest ..

[image]

but when i do the evaluation matrix " F1 , precision and recall " am getting NB with the highest value among the rest ..

is this normal or am i doing something wrong?

[image]

i used the same code to calculate metrics for each of the classification :

```
RFclf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=20)
#Train the model using the training sets y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
RFclf.fit(X_train,y_train)
train_pred=RFclf.predict(X_train)
test_pred=RFclf.predict(X_test)

rftrain = metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, train_pred)
rftest = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, test_pred)

print("Accuracy for Random Forest Test data on the test set: ",rftest)    
frftest = f1_score(y_test, test_pred) 
prftest = precision_score(y_test, test_pred) 
rrftest = recall_score(y_test, test_pred)
```

and used this code to do the plot :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax = plt.subplot(111)

models = ['SVM ','NB','Decision Tree ','LR','KNN','RF']
values = [pSVMtest ,pGAcc ,pdesicionT ,pLRAcc ,pKNAcc ,prftest]
model = np.arange(len(models))

plt.bar(model+0.15, values, align='center', width = 0.15, alpha=0.7, color = 'blue', label =         
'precision')
plt.xticks(model, models)



ax = plt.subplot(111)

models = ['SVM ','NB','Decision Tree ','LR','KNN','RF']
values = [rSVMtest ,rGAcc ,rdesicionT ,rLRAcc ,rKNAcc ,rrftest]
model = np.arange(len(models))

plt.bar(model+0.3, values, align='center', width = 0.15, alpha=0.7, color = 'green', label =         
'recall')
plt.xticks(model, models)

ax = plt.subplot(111)

models = ['SVM ','NB','Decision Tree ','LR','KNN','RF']
values = [fSVMtest ,fGAcc ,fdesicionT ,fLRAcc ,fKNAcc ,frftest]
model = np.arange(len(models))


plt.bar(model+0.45, values, align='center', width = 0.15, alpha=0.7, color = 'red', label =     
'F1 score')
plt.xticks(model, models)



plt.ylabel('Performance Metrics for Different models')
plt.title('Model')

# removing the axis on the top and right of the plot window
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: To test, I recommend take only one model, then, plot the confusion matrix of this model, and the precision, recall and F1 score. After that, calculate the precision, recall and F1 score **manually** (using your formula). Check if both values correspond. Also, check if these values correspond with your graphic. With this step, we will know where the mistake exactly is.

Comment: If your data is *imbalanced* (as I highly suspect they are), accuracy is not helpful as a performance metric.

Comment: i did the balancing using the smote method for the train set .. but still i feel like somthing doesnt look right